# Allow IAM user to access specific folder in AWS S3 Bucket to view and upload objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have multiple s3 buckets, i need to allow one s3 bucket folder access to IAM user to upload and view objects. can some one assist me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to grant specific IAM User(s) access to particular folders within an Amazon S3 bucket, you can create an IAM Policy and attach it to the user.

From [User policy examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-policies-s3.html#iam-policy-ex1):

> To grant each user access only to his or her folder, you can write a policy for each user and attach it individually. For example, you can attach the following policy to user Alice to allow her specific Amazon S3 permissions on the `awsexamplebucket1/Alice` folder.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/Alice/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListBucketOfASpecificUserPrefix",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "Alice/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to do this for **multiple users**, the easiest way is to create a single policy and **attach it to an IAM Group**, the put the users in the group. This policy will grant them access to a folder with the same name as their username:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1/${aws:username}/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListBucketOfASpecificUserPrefix",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsexamplebucket1",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${aws:username}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried to attach policy to user, still  i face issue. error in s3 console as follows. 
You don't have permissions to list buckets
After you or your AWS administrator have updated your permissions to allow the s3:ListAllMyBuckets action, refresh this page. Learn more about Identity and access management in Amazon S3

Comment: Have mapped below given policy to user

{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
         ],
         "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::sample-dev-test-bucket/upload/*"
      }
   ]
}

Comment: I have updated the policies to also allow listing of the bucket, within those specific Prefixes.